# Загрузиться с под UEFI

Tags: администрирование, bios, uefi

Устанавливал Windows 10 x64 через SCCM PE на производственную машину, вставил новый hdd  4 тб. SCCM форматировала диск на gpt и машина его не видела (то флешку, то DVD-ром начинал форматировать перед установкой)(смотрел в логах)

Bios не видит больше 2 тб. Других дисков нет, а 4 тб жалко разбивать на 2 тб. Установку делаю через локальную сеть. Заходя в bios я видел загрузка net и выбор bios или uefi с приоритетами.

Ставил net первый список в UEFI, все равно не видело диск 4 тб. Перед запуском пк хотел выбрать место откуда загружаться и кроме "Legacy Boot -> net" другого выбора не было.

Как загрузиться с под UEFI?

Есть рабочая мануалка? Поделитесь опытом )

Comment: Ставь ссд и не парься =) а 4 своих тб сделай облаком.

Comment: нет ssd,это бы решила конечно проблему.

Comment: Надо грузится с UEFI, например с DVD UEFI, тогда "видеть" диск будет не bios, а uefi загрузчик

Comment: "Bios не видит больше 2 тб. Других дисков нет, а 4 тб жалко разбивать на 2 тб. " - Что значит жалко, если это решает проблему? Нет разницы, и даже лучше - для скорости работы - поиска, например, да и вообще - большие объемы одним куском для долговременного хранения хорошо.

Comment: TЕсли можно загрузиться с под UEFI и установить на 4 тб, зачем терять 2 тб, я найду куда их деть.

Comment: Видимо у вас дохленький контроллер 1.5 гб/c максимально, а диск на 3 гб/c, По этому когда разделяется  происходит снижении скорости и он распознается... Попробуйте поиграться с перемычками и снизить скорость до 1.5 гб/c